# Honda Accord 2004 V6 Australian, Can stopped in the middle of the road

Tags: engine

Recently, when I was driving and had to stop at a set of light the car all of a sudden stopped. All the lights on the spedometer came up, but the A/C, radio all was working fine. I turned it off and tried again did not start up, (did this for 3 times). Eventually it started, and after around 300 Meters it stopped again. I parked my car in a car park, opened the hood to see if there was anything visibly wrong (nothing I could see). I left the car off for another 15 mins and tried again and it started up and turned off again after 55 seconds. This was the case again when I tried after 20 mins (before this I reset the battery). I called the road side assistance guy and he took around more then 1 hour to reach me. When he came, the car turned on and he took it for a spin and did not have any problems at all, it was on for more then 5 mins while we were doing the paperwork. The road side assistant also advised me that the computer in my car has not returned any errors. Please advise me of if anyone of you guys have experienced this sort of issues.

thanking you greatly,

Regards,
Ilesh

Answer (score 2):

I know first hand how aggrevating these intermittant problems can be. It is hard to fix something that won't stay broken. This sounds like a very typical fuel pump relay failure. For some reason older Honda fuel pump relays fail when they get warm. After it has cooled off it works fine. With the help of an assistant you may be able to verify the fault. the next time it won't start, (hopefully you are somewhere safe like a parking lot). While your assistant turns the ignition key to the "on" position listen for the sound of the fuel pump running. It is easiest to hear near the fuel fill door. You may want to remove the gas cap and put your ear near the filler neck. Listen carefully as the pump will only run for about five seconds before it shuts off. The relay location varies with makes and models. But under the dash near the steering column is a good start. If you don't hear the pump run it will give your mechanic a direction to troubleshoot.